# Java line not available when creating an object?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

Trying to create an object and adding it to an ArrayList. Code looks similar to this:

```
class B{
    public ArrayList<Answer> answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();

    questionList.add(new EssayQuestion());
    answerList.add(new StringAnswer());
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Test.createNewQuestion(Test.java:31)
at main.Survey.<init>(Survey.java:21)
at main.Test.<init>(Test.java:9)
at main.MainDriver.main(MainDriver.java:35)
```

And in the debugger, right before the crash I get this:
    `Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable) line: not available`

It's crashing at
`answerList.add(new StringAnswer());`
and I have no idea why.

If it's relevant, questionList is initialized in the superclass of where this code chunk is. I am accessing it because it is protected. answerList is created locally.

The constructor of StringAnswer asks the user for a String and reads it via Scanner. EssayQuestion()'s constructor is very similar.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is some more code as requested. Yes, answerList is showing as null after initialized and before anything gets added. Is that the problem? Why is it happening? Once again, questionList is declared and initialized in the parent class of this, so it's okay not to re-declare or initialize it right?

```
public class Test extends Survey
 {
  public ArrayList<Answer> answerList;

  public Test()
  {
            answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    System.out.print("How many questions? ");
    int numQuestions = kb.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++)
    {
        displayMenu();
        createNewQuestion();
    }
   }

   public void createNewQuestion()
   {
    int input = -1;
    do{
        System.out.print("Question Type: ");
        input = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:     questionList.add(new EssayQuestion());
                        answerList.add(new StringAnswer());
                        break;
```

And here is StringAnswer:

```
public class StringAnswer extends Answer
{
String text;

public StringAnswer()
{
    setAnswer();

}

public StringAnswer(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public void display()
{
    System.out.println(text);       
}

public String getAnswer()
{
    return text;
}

@Override
public void setAnswer()
{
    System.out.print("Enter Answer: ");
    setAnswer(kb.nextLine());
    System.out.println("");
}

public void setAnswer(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}

}
```

Comment: If it's crashing at `answerList.add(new StringAnswer());` then `answerList` is clearly `null`. Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: if your code is not too big, can you post it instead of `similar code` you posted.

Comment: Yes, anserList is null before anything gets added to it. I will post a larger code block as requested.

Comment: Please share your `StringAnswer` constructor.

Comment: What is `questionList`? Is it an ArrayList? If yes, then where have you declared and initialized it?

Comment: I've added StringAnswer.

Comment: This is a mess.  Please reduce your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), i.e. something short and concise that will compile and execute, that demonstrates the problem.  If you don't find the error in the process of doing this, then either edit your question or delete this one and post a new one. RIght now all you're getting are bad guesses because the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments to @D_Jones's answer, I assume you've something like this:

```
public class Survey{
    protected ArrayList<EssayQuestion> questionList;

    //your parent class methods;
}
```

And after that you're accessing questionList and trying to add elements to it from your Test class. The problem over here is this that you've not instantiated questionList. This means that questionList is still null and when you're trying to add elements to questionList, you're thrown a NullPointerException by the JVM.

There're a couple of solutions to it:

**Solution 1**: Instantiate questionList in the base class constructor. Something like this:

```
public class Survey{
    protected ArrayList<EssayQuestion> questionList;

    public Survey(){
        questionList = new ArrayList<EssayQuestion>();
    }
    //your parent class methods;
}
```

Now you can access it in your child class without an exception.

**Solution 2**: Instantiate it within the constructor of your child class or wherever you're trying to use it for the first time.

```
public class Survey{
    protected ArrayList<EssayQuestion> questionList;

    //your parent class methods;
}


public class Test extends Survey
{
  public ArrayList<Answer> answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();

  public Test(){
    questionList = new ArrayList<EssayQuestion>(); //Option 1
  }

  public void createNewQuestion(){
    //If you've not initialized it in the constructor, try instantiating it in on first use
    if(questionList == null){ //Option 2
        questionList = new ArrayList<EssayQuestion>();
    }

    //now you can access the questionList without an exception.
    //this is because you've a valid instance of of ArrayList<EssayQuestion> to which the
    //variable questionList points to
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sujay. QuestionList is declared and initialized properly, and can hold `Question`s fine. The problem is with `answerList`. I have tried initializing it in the constructor, and right before the constructor. It's value in the debugger is still showing as null.

Comment: @iaacp: What is there in line 31 - the place where you encounter the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you are calling `createNewQuestion()` within the constructor.  I am not sure what if anything is guaranteed about order of processing when constructing an instance of a class.  It is possible that the code in the constructor is executing before the initialization of `answerList`.

Try moving the initialization (but not the declaration) of `answerList` into the constructor.

Another possible issue is that your constructor for Test is not calling its super-class's constructor.  The first line of your constructor should be `super();`.

(You seem to be confused, by the way, about the difference between `null` and "empty".  If the initialization of `answerList` completes successfully, then it's not null, but it points to an empty list.)

**Followup**

I was misremembering how superclass constructors work.  In fact, even if you don't explicitly call `super()`, the superclass constructor is automatically invoked.  "If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

And I should have realized this from the stack trace of the exception. The stack shows that `Test()` is calling `Survey()` which is then calling `Test.createNewQuestion()`.  From your comment about the two constructors being very similar, this is not surprising.

I still think the likely cause of the problem is the order in which things are being executed.  There is probably no way to cause `answerList` to be initialized before `Survey()` is called.

This brings me to the advice I wanted to give in the first place, which is that you simply shouldn't be doing all this stuff in constructors -- especially user interaction.  I'd say you should probably have a static method in each class called something like `createInstance()`, which collects the user input and builds the list(s) as local variables, then calls a constructor which takes those lists as arguments.

Comment: I don't want to call super(); because `Test`'s  constructor is very similar with some minor tweaks. So I copied and pasted, and added what needed to be added. I tried just declaring outside the constructor, then initializing inside the constructor. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off-base here because I am still relatively new to java, but did you declare questionList?  The posted code does not show a declaration for questionList.  As I said I am still relatively new to Java and it is my first day on this site.  Needless to say I have a lot I need to learn still.

Comment: From what I understand, because I declared questionList in the parent of this class, and this class extends that, I can use it freely. I encapsulated it with protected.

Comment: @iaacp: So you've declared `questionList` in a parent class. However where have you instantiate it? The reason that you're getting the NullPointerException is because you have not instantiated this variable.

Comment: ahhh ok. So it was declared protected.  Sorry, I missed this completely on the first pass of reading this.  Still studying the code to see if I can figure out something.

Comment: Sujay, questionList was declared and initialized in the parent class.